# How to provide and pass "object" to the viewmodelbase?

Tags: c#, xaml, mvvm, uwp

I just started to do MVVM because a have heard a lot of its benefits about:

1. Clean code
2. Reusable code
3. Better code organized

So started to do a usual "Code behind" to make sure that my code is working, and then apply MVVM to clean it up. 
so here is one of my "code behind" example:

```
private const int LED_PIN = 17, RELAY_PIN = 27;
private GpioPin LEDpin, RELAYpin;

    private bool InitGPIO(TextBlock txt)
    {
        var gpio = GpioController.GetDefault();

        // Show an error if there is no GPIO controller
        if (gpio == null)
        {
            txt.Text = "There is no GPIO controller on this device.";
            txt.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
            return false;
        }

        txt.Text = "GPIO controller initialized correctly.";
        txt.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Green);

        LEDpin = gpio.OpenPin(LED_PIN);
        RELAYpin = gpio.OpenPin(RELAY_PIN);
        LEDpinValue = GpioPinValue.Low;
        RELAYpinValue = GpioPinValue.High;
        LEDpin.Write(LEDpinValue);
        RELAYpin.Write(RELAYpinValue);
        LEDpin.SetDriveMode(GpioPinDriveMode.Output);
        RELAYpin.SetDriveMode(GpioPinDriveMode.Output);
        return true;
    }
```

To use this "InitGPIO" method I have to provide:

1. fixed "int" pin.
2. GpioPin types.
3. GpioPinValue type.
4. A textblock to display what is wrong.

I already create a ViewModelBase and the simplify method to get it read:

```
public class ViewModelBase
{
    public InitGpioCommand InitGpiocommand { get; set; }
    public ViewModelBase() 
    {
        this.InitGpiocommand = new InitGpioCommand(this);
    }

    public bool InitGPIO(DigitalControl dc)
    {
        var gpio = GpioController.GetDefault();

        // Show an error if there is no GPIO controller
        if (gpio == null)
        {
            dc.Status.Text = "There is no GPIO controller on this device.";
            dc.Status.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
            return false;
        }

        dc.Status.Text = "GPIO controller initialized correctly.";
        dc.Status.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Green);

        dc.DevicePin = gpio.OpenPin(dc.PinNumber);
        dc.PinValue = GpioPinValue.Low;
        dc.DevicePin.Write(dc.PinValue);
        dc.DevicePin.SetDriveMode(GpioPinDriveMode.Output);
        return true;
    }
}
```

everything had been wrap up in this Model:

```
public class DigitalControl
{
    public TextBlock Status { get; set; }
    public GpioPin DevicePin  { get; set; }
    public GpioPinValue PinValue { get; set; }
    public int PinNumber { get; set; }
}
```

and my current button to fire the InitGPIO method:

```
   <Button x:Name="FirstLightTest"
           Content="Test" 
           Command="{Binding InitGPIO,Source={StaticResource viewmodel}}">
   </Button>
```

Of course this will not work.

I realize I have to:

1. Pass a "TextBlock" from xaml to the method parameter in ViewModelBase.
2. Assign GpioPin, GpioPinValue and PinNumber somewhere in C# code and also pass them to the Method inside the ViewModelBase.

In order to fill up all the parameters in that method. 
I don't really know this is a bad MVVM design or not but I think the best to use this complicated pattern is to break it down smaller problems like this and see if how valuable it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some mix-ups in the code. First of all, the `Binding` is bound to `InitGIPO`, which is a method. This will not work as `Command` can be bound to a `ICommand` property only. In this case, the proper target would be the `InitGpiocommand`. I always recommend using an existing MVVM framework as a starting point, for example the MVVM Light framework or MvvmCross. Those provide the implementation of a simple `DelegateCommand` which can just call a simple parameterless method. You could then have the method look like this:

```
private bool InitGPIO()
{
    ...
}
```

Now, where do we get the `DigitalControl` instance? We will add a property to our view model that will represent this instance:

```
public DigitalControl DigitalControl { get; } = new DigitalControl();
```

As @max already mentioned, it definitely discouraged to put UI controls into any View Model properties, so let's change the definition of `DigitalControl` to this:

```
public class DigitalControl
{
    public string Status { get; set; }
    public GpioPin DevicePin  { get; set; }
    public GpioPinValue PinValue { get; set; }
    public int PinNumber { get; set; }
}
```

The `Status` property can now be *data-bound* to the `TextBlock`, like this:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding DigitalControl.Status, Mode=TwoWay}" .../>
```

Once the user modifies the `TextBlock`, the change will automatically propagate to the view model's `DigitalControl` instance's `Status` property.

To reference the `DigitalControl` property in `InitGIPO` you can just reference it as any other property within the view model.

Comment: Wait what about the step that assign value ?
`private const int LED_PIN = 17, RELAY_PIN = 27;`

Comment: I am not sure what you mean, could you please update the answer with the new code so I can see better :-) ?

Answer (score 1):

To me having a UI component (`TextBlock`) inside a model is a violation of MVVM-pattern. Instead the `TextBlock`'s properties  should be bound to the view-model via binding mechanism and not assigned directly.
To sum up:

1. Remove the `TextBlock` reference from the model
2. Provide properties in the view-model that `TextBlock` can be bound to (text, foreground color or a boolean flag).
3. Bind to the view-model properties from xaml.

Comment: Thanks Max, I obviously don't really see this coming. Because make a lot of sense when code behind, btw nice tips. I love it